# Issue with mangopay php sdk

Tags: php, mangopay

I'm using mangopay with the official sdk 3.11, i get following error :

```
Call to undefined method MangoPay\MangoPayApi::getLogger()
```

Here how i use the API :

```
namespace App\Services;

use MangoPay\MangoPayApi;

class MangopayServices
{
    private $api;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api = new MangoPayApi();
        $this->api->Config->ClientId = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
        $this->api->Config->ClientPassword = 'MY_API_KEY';
        $this->api->Config->TemporaryFolder = '/home/site/mgpy';
    }
    public function get_users()
    {
        return $this->api->Users->GetAll();
    }
}
```

When call this service :

```
$s = new App\Services\MangopayServices();
dump($s->get_users())
```

i get fatal error : **Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MangoPay\MangoPayApi::getLogger()**

Have you any idea please ?

Thank you

Comment: is it happening in the constructor or on the `get_users()` method?

Comment: On the get_users() method, un dump to the constructor output the mangopay object